# Optimizing Mesh Generator

Tags: algorithm, performance, generator, mesh, cube

I have a plain mesh generator that takes an array of cube positions and calculates visible faces of them. This algorithm takes too much time (obviously), it runs only once though. How should I optimize this thing so it would work faster? I don't think chunks are acceptable, maybe I should use another data structure or process positions differently. I hope you'll help me out with this. Thanks.

```
Mesh MeshGenerator::GenerateMesh(std::vector<glm::vec3>& rawData)
{
    Mesh mesh;
    MeshFace meshFace;

    bool left = false;
    bool right = false;
    bool front = false;
    bool back  = false;
    bool down = false;
    bool up = false;

    int count = 0;

    // Iterating thorugh blocks
    for (glm::vec3 blockOrigin : rawData)
    {
        for (glm::vec3 block2Origin : rawData) {            

            // X: to left
            if (block2Origin.x - blockOrigin.x == -1
                && block2Origin.y - blockOrigin.y == 0
                && block2Origin.z - blockOrigin.z == 0)
            {
                left = true;
                count++;
            }

            // X: to right
            if (block2Origin.x - blockOrigin.x == 1
                && block2Origin.y - blockOrigin.y == 0
                && block2Origin.z - blockOrigin.z == 0)
            {
                right = true;
                count++;
            }


            // Z: to front
            if (block2Origin.z - blockOrigin.z == 1
                && block2Origin.x - blockOrigin.x == 0
                && block2Origin.y - blockOrigin.y == 0)
            {
                front = true;
                count++;
            }

            // Z: to back
            if (block2Origin.z - blockOrigin.z == -1
                && block2Origin.x - blockOrigin.x == 0
                && block2Origin.y - blockOrigin.y == 0)
            {
                back = true;
                count++;
            }

            // Y: to down
            if (block2Origin.y - blockOrigin.y == -1
                && block2Origin.x - blockOrigin.x == 0
                && block2Origin.z - blockOrigin.z == 0)
            {
                down = true;
                count++;
            }

            // Y: to up
            if (block2Origin.y - blockOrigin.y == 1
                && block2Origin.x - blockOrigin.x == 0
                && block2Origin.z - blockOrigin.z == 0)
            {
                up = true;
                count++;
            }

            if (count == 6) break;
            count = 0;              
        }

        if (!left)
        {
            meshFace.Color = glm::vec4(1,1,1,1);
            meshFace.Position = blockOrigin;
            meshFace.Face = 0;
            mesh.AddMeshFace(meshFace);
        }

        if (!right)
        {
            meshFace.Color = glm::vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);
            meshFace.Position = blockOrigin;
            meshFace.Face = 1;
            mesh.AddMeshFace(meshFace);
        }

        if (!front)
        {
            meshFace.Color = glm::vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);
            meshFace.Position = blockOrigin;
            meshFace.Face = 2;
            mesh.AddMeshFace(meshFace);
        }

        if (!back)
        {
            meshFace.Color = glm::vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);
            meshFace.Position = blockOrigin;
            meshFace.Face = 3;
            mesh.AddMeshFace(meshFace);
        }
        if (!down)
        {
            meshFace.Color = glm::vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);
            meshFace.Position = blockOrigin;
            meshFace.Face = 4;
            mesh.AddMeshFace(meshFace);
        }
        if (!up)
        {
            meshFace.Color = glm::vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);
            meshFace.Position = blockOrigin;
            meshFace.Face = 5;
            mesh.AddMeshFace(meshFace);
        }

        left = false;
        right = false;
        front = false;
        back = false;
        down = false;
        up = false;

        count = 0;
    }


    return mesh;
```

Comment: Using == comparisons with floating-point values is pretty dangerous. The algorithm seems to not match with the (rather small) description or to contain bugs. Indeed, the two first inner conditions will never be true simultaneously, so `count` cannot reach the value 6 and the loop will never stop prematurely and `count` will always be reset to 0... As a result,  `count` increments are useless. Finally, it seems the algorithm works on cube vertices and not "cube positions", as stated in the post. Can you clarify the description, please?

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks for the reply. Count variable was added to prevent iterating through the loop if all of the neighbor cubes were found. Yes, resetting count in the first loop is a mistake, thanks for spotting it. Cube position is actually cube vertex (so called origin in code). Vertices (one vertex per cube) of all cubes have the same stride between each other (1 unit, length of cube edge). The origin of the cube is located at the bottom left vertex of front face. By the way, renderer only needs to know what cube position and face (number from 0 to 5) of that cube to use.